# Code Formatting and Intellassist

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, coderush-xpress

I'm using VB.NET in VS2008 professional. Just installed Coderush Xpress 11.2.10. Code formatting and intellasist doesn't work.

I tried Edit->Advanced->Format Document but VS keeps formatting in its standard VB way without coderush configuration.

Intellasist never shows nothing. Even with intellisense deactivated in VS.

Can somebody help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I regret to inform you that neither Intellassist nor Code Formatting for Visual Basic is available in the free CodeRush Xpress version.